# Having trouble blocking player's path in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble blocking the player's path they already went through. I have the player leave a trail of slime that there are not suppose to go through. I'm using sublime text

```js
// Put your global variables after this line
var GRIDWIDTH, GRIDHEIGHT;
GRIDWIDTH = 11;
GRIDHEIGHT = 13;
var player = new Object();
player.x = 0;
player.y = 0;
var reset = 0x0052;
var GAME_WON = false;
var foodValue = 1;

var PlayerInventory = {
  key: 0,
  food: 0,
  foodLeft: 0,

}



// Put your function definitions after this line
function drawPlayer(x, y) {
  PS.color(x, y, PS.COLOR_GREEN);
  PS.glyphColor(x, y, PS.COLOR_WHITE);
  PS.glyph(x, y, "ඬ");
  player.x = x;
  player.y = y;
}

function drawSlime(x, y, dir) {
  PS.color(x, y, PS.COLOR_GREEN);
  PS.data(x, y, dir);
  PS.data(x, y, "wall")
}

function PlaceKey(x, y) {
  PS.color(x, y, PS.COLOR_YELLOW);
  PS.glyphColor(x, y, PS.COLOR_ORANGE);
  PS.glyph(x, y, "K")
  PS.data(x, y, "key");
}

function removePlayer(x, y) {

  PS.glyph(x, y, 0);
}


function isInGrid(x, y) {
  if (x < 0) return false;
  else if (x >= GRIDWIDTH) return false;
  else if (y < 0) return false;
  else if (y >= GRIDHEIGHT) return false;
  else return true;
}

function CreateButtons() {
  PS.glyph(5, 12, reset);


  PS.data(5, 12, "resetbutton");

}

function DrawInventory() {
  PS.statusText(" key: " + PlayerInventory.key + "food: " + PlayerInventory.food);
}

function PlaceFood(x, y) {
    PS.glyph(x, y, 0x25CE);
    PS.glyphColor(x, y, 0xBA9A19);
    PS.data(x, y, "food");
    PlayerInventory.foodLeft += foodValue;


  }
  

// PS.keyDown ( key, shift, ctrl, options )
  // Called when a key on the keyboard is pressed
PS.keyDown = function(key, shift, ctrl, options) {
  "use strict";

  // Uncomment the following line to inspect parameters
  // PS.debug( "PS.keyDown(): key = " + key + ", shift = " + shift + ", ctrl = " + ctrl + "\n" );

  // Add code here for when a key is pressed

  
  if (GAME_WON) {
    GameSetup();
  } else {
    var oldX = player.x;
    var oldY = player.y;

    // Moves the player in the game with the key arrow
    if (key == PS.KEY_ARROW_RIGHT && (player.x < (GRIDWIDTH - 1)))
      player.x += 1;
    else if (key == PS.KEY_ARROW_LEFT && (player.x > 0))
      player.x -= 1;
    else if (key == PS.KEY_ARROW_UP && (player.y > 0))
      player.y -= 1;
    else if (key == PS.KEY_ARROW_DOWN && (player.y < (GRIDHEIGHT - 1)))
      player.y += 1;

    var dataAtPlayer = PS.data(player.x, player.y);

    if (dataAtPlayer == "wall") {
      player.x = oldX;
      player.y = oldY;
    }

    if (dataAtPlayer == "drawSlime") {
      player.x = oldX;
      player.y = oldY;
    }

    if (dataAtPlayer == "leaf") {
      if (PlayerInventory.key > -0) {
        PS.audioPlay("fx_blast4");
        DrawInventory();

      } else {
        player.x = oldX;
        player.y = oldY;
      }
    }


    if (dataAtPlayer == "key") {
      PlayerInventory.key += 1;
      DrawInventory();
      PS.audioPlay("fx_pop");
    }
    if (dataAtPlayer == "food") {
      PlayerInventory.foodLeft -= foodValue;
      PlayerInventory.foods += foodValue;
      DrawInventory();
      PS.audioPlay("fx_tada");
      if (PlayerInventory.foodLeft == 0) {
        GAME_WON = true;
        PS.statusText("Click R to restar!");
      }
    }


    drawPlayer(player.x, player.y);

  }
};
```

I tried to fix this issue by changing the code to this:

```js
// WASD keys to move The Snail
if (key == 119) {
  //Check that up isn’t a wall
  //Check that up isn’t off the screen
  if (player.y - 1 >= 0) {
    if (PS.data(player.x, player.y - 1) != "wall") {
      //If both are true, remove player from current position
      //If both are true, draw player in new position
      removePlayer(player.x, player.y);
      drawPlayer(player.x, player.y - 1);
      drawSlime(player.x, player.y);
    }
  }
}
if (key == 115) {
  //Check that down isn’t a wall
  //Check that down isn’t off the screen
  if (player.y + 1 < GRIDHEIGHT) {
    if (PS.data(player.x, player.y + 1) != "wall") {
      //If both are true, remove player from current position
      //If both are true, draw player in new position
      removePlayer(player.x, player.y);
      drawPlayer(player.x, player.y + 1);
      drawSlime(player.x, player.y);
    }
  }
}
if (key == 97) {
  //Check that left isn’t a wall
  //Check that left isn’t off the screen
  if (player.x - 1 >= 0) {
    if (PS.data(player.x - 1, player.y) != "wall") {
      //If both are true, remove player from current position
      //If both are true, draw player in new position
      removePlayer(player.x, player.y);
      drawPlayer(player.x - 1, player.y);
      drawSlime(player.x, player.y);

    }
  }
}
if (key == 100) {
  //Check that right isn’t a wall
  //Check that right isn’t off the screen
  if (player.x + 1 < GRIDWIDTH) {
    if (PS.data(player.x + 1, player.y) != "wall") {
      //If both are true, remove player from current position
      //If both are true, draw player in new position
      removePlayer(player.x, player.y);
      drawPlayer(player.x + 1, player.y);
      drawSlime(player.x, player.y);
    }
  }
}
```

And while this worked, I wasn't able to interact with the items in the game,

Comment: When I ran code snippet I got blank page for both...

Comment: What is the problem? How does this snippet reproduce your problem? Also, it's not relevant what text editor you are using.

Comment: Seems to be using [Perlenspiel](http://users.wpi.edu/~bmoriarty/ps/index.html)

Comment: I'm using perlenspiel to make the game. What I'm trying to do is prevent the player from moving through the slime but the first code doesn't work. While the second code blocks the player path in the slime is in the way, I can't pick up any of the items I have placed like the key and food while also going through a leaf wall I have placed that they shouldn't be going through without a key.